# Reading a Text file with arrays in it - to display in table

Tags: php, arrays, file, text

I am hoping someone can point in the right direction here, been surfing the internet for hours and haven't found a solution.

First, I am an "OKAY" php coder .. so this might be obvi but I am lost.

I have a txt file with array() in from a pull in an api transaction list.

```
    Array
    (
        [orderid] => 00000000
        [type] => rebill
        [paystatus] => cancelled
    )

    Array
    (
        [orderid] => 000000
        [type] => rebill
        [paystatus] => cancelled
    )
Array
(
    [orderid] => 000000
    [type] => refund
    [paystatus] => cancelled
    [productid] => 939399393
    [firstName] => XXXXXX
    [lastName] => XXXX
    [customeremail] => XXXX
    [amount] => XX.XX
    [refunddate] => 2015-01-01
    [refundstatus] => ok
)
```

There is thousands of these array()'s ... I am use to dealing with json etc to pull for each, but right now I am lost completely.

I am able to replicate the file with

```
$f = fopen("merged.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while(!feof($f)) { 
    echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
}

fclose($f);
```

... that's it

I have played around with all kinds of foreach while etc and can't get it to work.
If someone could point in the right direction, I would appreciate it so much.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats your actual question it seems to be unclear

Comment: merging all the array() into one. I know - that the dude below nailed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about try this?

```
$content= file_get_contents("merged.txt");

$arrays = explode('Array',ltrim(trim($content),'Array'));

echo "<table>";
foreach($arrays as $key => $value){
    $value = text_to_array("Array".$value);
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $value['orderid'];
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";




function text_to_array($str) {

    //Initialize arrays
    $keys = array();
    $values = array();
    $output = array();

    //Is it an array?
    if( substr($str, 0, 5) == 'Array' ) {

        //Let's parse it (hopefully it won't clash)
        $array_contents = substr($str, 7, -2);
        $array_contents = str_replace(array(' ', '[', ']', '=>'), array('', '#!#', '#?#', ''), $array_contents);
        $array_fields = explode("#!#", $array_contents);

        //For each array-field, we need to explode on the delimiters I've set and make it look funny.
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array_fields); $i++ ) {

            //First run is glitched, so let's pass on that one.
            if( $i != 0 ) {

                $bits = explode('#?#', $array_fields[$i]);
                if( $bits[0] != '' ) $output[$bits[0]] = $bits[1];

            }
        }

        //Return the output.
        return $output;

    } else {

        //Duh, not an array.
        echo 'The given parameter is not an array.';
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thanks, that's 100% what I was looking for. Appreciate that.

Comment: woah.Glad i helped mate

Comment: Now just trying to put that into a table. I am use to working with JSON api stuff ... plain array stuff I haven't done before.

Comment: you can `foreach` the `$arrays` to get the values

Comment: like ...foreach($array as $key=>$value)

Comment: Maybe I am getting tired but it's not working at all foreach($arrays as $key=>$value) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $value['orderid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $value['type'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => 
(
    [orderid] => 680006562
    [type] => rebill
    [paystatus] => cancelled
)


    [1] => 
(
    [orderid] => 680006562
    [type] => rebill
    [paystatus] => cancelled
)
`

Answer (score 0):

First create a PHP file for that all arrays. NOT A TXT FILE.

Then need to do one change for all the array is define each array in each variable.

```
$var1 = Array
    (
        [orderid] => 00000000
        [type] => rebill
        [paystatus] => cancelled
    )
```

Then just use value by,

```
echo $var1['orderid'];
```

Thanks

Comment: So something like ... $var1 = file_get_contents(merged.php) ?

Comment: No. Create a php file like, **arrays.php**. Then include that file in your listing page by, **include_once('array.php');** function. Then u can access all arrays in your listing page. To use particular array u have to give it a name like **$var1**. Now u can access that array by **$var1**. Now you want array's **orderid** then just write **echo $var1['orderid'];**. By passing a **key** in **$var1** you can access that value.

Comment: If you have a confusion in **array** fundamentals then follow this link,

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I have a text file that an api wrote too with thousands of array() - for some reason it didn't dump like array( array[0]() array[1]()) ----- I need to display them in a table. I understand arrays, what I don't know is how to merge them all into ONE ARRAY so I can get the data and display it. What you're saying doesn't make sense to ... there is no way I can add var1 var2 to thousands of these manually.